# JTable with cell flashing

Tags: java, swing, timer, jtable, renderer

I am writing an application using the Swing library in Java. I have a table component that extends `JTable`, and in this component I have overridden the method `getTableCellRendererComponent`, because I color the cells of the table. I have a custom table model (that extends from the default table model), and the table component itself I have added to a JPanel. All this works.

Now I would like to add to this table, some functionality to have a cell flashing. Potentially, more than one cell can be flashing at a time, i.e. cells at (row 1, column 2) and (row 3, column 4).

Is this possible to do? Any hints that could get me started would be appreciated.

Comment: yes is possible, nothing special, edit your question with an [SSCCE](http://sscce.org/)  demonstrating your issue(s), but after reading [JTable tutorial](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/table.html#editrender)

Comment: I'd use a listener. I think ActionListener will do the trick

Comment: How actionListener will make it flashing, you will have to use something like a timer to get this done

Comment: While cell flashing is possible, consider other aspects such changing the background color. It may be more user-friendly. If you go with flashing, just create a Timer and on every tick flash the appropriate cells.

Comment: `Random` for generating a `Color` & `Swing Timer` & `XxxRenderer`, or is possible to change (better and easiest way) `Swing Timer` with `Runnable#Thread` dealyed with `Thread.sleep(int)`

Comment: Ok but i don't know as to realize it.... Can we send me some somple?

Answer (score 3):

I find one article for your answer:

http://www.devx.com/DevX/10MinuteSolution/17167/0/page/1

The page provide the source code for downloading.

Basically it use following method to notify table to update the cell timely.

```
JTable.tableChanged(new TableModelEvent(table.getModel(), firstRow, lastRow, column));
```

After reading his code, I sort out a simpler version of his code, you can change my code or use his code (more elegant but also more complex).

```
public class FlashCellTable
{
    public static Color color;

    public static void main(String[] args)
    {
        JFrame frame = new JFrame();
        frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.DISPOSE_ON_CLOSE);
        frame.setLocationRelativeTo(null);
        frame.setSize(800, 600);

        final JTable table = new JTable(4, 4);
        table.setDefaultRenderer(Object.class, new MyFlashingCellRenderer());
        table.setValueAt("Flashing", 0, 0);
        frame.getContentPane().add(new JScrollPane(table));

        final long startTime = System.currentTimeMillis();

        Thread thread = new Thread()
        {
            @Override
            public void run()
            {
                while (true)
                {
                    long now = System.currentTimeMillis();
                    long second = (now - startTime) / 1000;
                    color = second / 2 * 2 == second ? Color.red : Color.blue;

                    System.out.println("FlashCellTable.run");

                    SwingUtilities.invokeLater(new Runnable()
                    {
                        public void run()
                        {
                            table.tableChanged(new TableModelEvent(table.getModel(), 0, 0, 0));  
                        }
                    });
                    try
                    {
                        Thread.sleep(1000);
                    }
                    catch(InterruptedException e)
                    {
                        e.printStackTrace();  //To change body of catch statement use File | Settings | File Templates.
                    }
                }
            }
        };

        thread.start();

        frame.setVisible(true);
    }

    public static class MyFlashingCellRenderer extends DefaultTableCellRenderer
    {
        @Override
        public Component getTableCellRendererComponent(JTable table, Object value, boolean isSelected, boolean hasFocus,
                                                       int row, int column)
        {
            JLabel label =
                (JLabel)super.getTableCellRendererComponent(table, value, isSelected, hasFocus, row, column);

            if ("Flashing".equals(value))
            {
                label.setBackground(color);
            }
            else
            {
                label.setBackground(Color.white);
            }
            return label;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: this example is reason why Swing Timer is there, btw +1

Comment: @mKorbel thanks for vote, and one small question, do I need put table.tableChanged() into a SwingUtilities.invokeLater() ? thanks

Comment: basically Swing doesn't know something about Thread, then all output (from Thread) to non_Thread_Safe methods (setText, appent e.g.) are out of EDT, answer is yes, required and its safest, Swing Timer is best way for that, rather than use Thread and with Thread.Sleep(int)

Comment: I think if you use a Swing timer it will do the job of handling the timer firing in the event thread for you.